# Where, how Caesar III?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, caesar-3

I used to play Caesar III on my power mac g3 (mac os 9) I have now a pc laptop and I was thinking where I could find it and how I could install it, what operating system I should use, ( I have Ubuntu 10.04 and mac os x 10.6 and win 7.)
simply my question is

Where can i find it?

How can I install it?

this might not be met, but I would love to find a mac version ( I have 5 macs).

Comment: What kind of title is that?

Comment: Sierra games! They also made "Pharaoh"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find it at [Good Old Games](http://www.gog.com/en/gamecard/caesar_3) and it will play on any version of Windows from Windows XP or later.

Comment: +1 for a great link. My childhood right there on one website! Ohh the memories :o)